# Find all groups of 9 digits (\d{9}) up to a certain word

Tags: regex, python-3.8

I have the following string extracted from a PDF file and I would like to obtain the nine digits "control class" number from it:

```
string = ‘(some text before)Process ID: JD7717PO CONTROL CLASS706345519,708393673, 706855190 CODE AAZ-1585 ZZF-8017. Sector: Name:MULTIBANK S.A. SAAT:  54177846900115Date of Production2019/12/20\x02.02.037SBPEAA201874249B\x0c(some text after)’
```

I want all the matches that occur before the word “Sector”, otherwise I will have undesired matches.
I’m using the “re” module, in Python 3.8.

I tried to use the negative lookbehind as follows:

```
(?<!Sector:)\d{9})
```

However, it didn’t work. I still had the matches like ‘54177846’ and ‘201874249’, which are after the ‘Sector’ word.

I also tried to “isolate” the search area between the words “Process ID” and “Sector”:

```
(Process ID:.*?)(\d{9})(.*Sector)
```

I also tried to search for the expression \d9 only up to the “Sector” word, but it returned no results.

I had to work a solution around, in two steps:  (1) I created a regex that would find all the results up to the word “Sector” (`desperate_regex = ‘(.*)Sector)’ and assigned it to a new variable,`partial_text`; (2) I then searched for the desired regex ('\d{9}') within the new variable.

My code is working, but it does not satisfies me. How would I find my matches with a single regex search?
Please note that the first "control class" number is truncated with the text that comes before it ("CONTROL CLASS706345519").

(PS: I'm a totally newbie, and this is my first post. I hope I could explain my self. Thank you!)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to get the string before `Sector` and just search that:

```
split_string, _ = string.split("Sector")
nums = re.findall(r'\d{9}', split_string)
# ['706345519', '708393673', '706855190']
```

Another would be to use the third-party [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/)  module, which allows overlapping matches:

```
import regex as re
nums = re.findall(r'(\d{9}).*?Sector', string, overlapped=True)
# ['706345519', '708393673', '706855190']
```

Comment: Thank you, Patrick!
Both solutions work great, but the second one is what I was looking for. 
I only knew the `re` module for Python, not the `regex`. I will read its documentation to learn more about it. 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The regex described below may be more overkill then required for the actual case being handled, but better safe than sorry.

If you want match a string of exactly 9 digits, no more no fewer, then you should you negative lookbehind and lookahead assertions to ensure that the 9 digits are not preceded nor followed by another digit (again, in this case perhaps the OP knows that only 9-digit numbers will ever appear and this is overkill). You can also use a negative lookbehind assertion to ensure that `Sector` does not appear before the 9 digits. This later assertion is a variable length assertion requiring the `regex` package from PyPI:

```
r'(?<!Sector.*?)(?<!\d)\d{9}(?!\d)'
```

1. `(?<!Sector.*?` Assert that we haven't scanned past `Sector`. This handles the situation where `Sector` might appear multiple times in the input by ensuring that we never scan past the first occurrence.
2. `(?<!\d)` Assert that the previous character is not a digit.
3. `\d{9}` Match 9 digits.
4. `(?!\d)` Assert that the next character is not a digit.

The simplified version:

```
r'(?<!Sector.*?)\d{9}'
```

The code:

```
import regex as re

string = '(some text before)Process ID: JD7717PO CONTROL CLASS706345519,708393673, 706855190 CODE AAZ-1585 ZZF-8017. Sector: Name:MULTIBANK S.A. SAAT:  54177846900115Date of Production2019/12/20\x02.02.037SBPEAA201874249B\x0c(some text after)'

#print(re.findall(r'(?<!Sector.*?)\d{9}', string))
print(re.findall(r'(?<!Sector.*?)(?<!\d)\d{9}(?!\d)', string))
```

Prints:

```
['706345519', '708393673', '706855190']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an alternation and break if you find "Sector":

```
import re
text = """(some text before)Process ID: JD7717PO CONTROL CLASS706345519,708393673, 706855190 CODE AAZ-1585 ZZF-8017. Sector: Name:MULTIBANK S.A. SAAT:  54177846900115Date of Production2019/12/20\x02.02.037SBPEAA201874249B\x0c(some text after)"""
rx = re.compile(r'\d{9}|(Sector)')

results = []
for match in rx.finditer(text):
    if match.group(1):
        break
    results.append(match.group(0))

print(results)
```

Which yields

```
['706345519', '708393673', '706855190']
```

Answer (score 0):

If either of these work I'll add an explaination to it:

`[\s\S]+(?:Process ID:\s+)(.*)(?:\s+Sector)[\s\S]+`

`\g<1>`

Or this?

`(?i)[\s\S]+(?:control\s+class\s*)(\d{9})[\s\S]+`

`\g<1>`

Comment: I couldn't pass these patterns to 're.compile(pattern)'.
Are they suited to run in Python 're' ou 'regex' modules?

I tried then on regex101.com, as PCRE(PHP), and the first one correctly isolated the relevant part of the search (it matched everything between "Process ID:" and "Sector"), but the second one only returned the first result ("706345519").

But Patrick's solution (above) worked. 
Thanks a lot.